# What is causing DbSet<T> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter error message?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am following the tutorial for the MVC version of Contoso University at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0

This tutorial is under .Net 7 documentation but they haven't updated it so it's still in .Net 5.

I'm on the Update related data module.

In the EditPost method,we add in this line near the top of the action:

```
var courseToUpdate = await _context.Courses;
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CourseID == id);
```

Now that line is underlined with the red squiggly and the error message is:

'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm seven modules into this tutorial and the DbContext has been working fine up until now.

I commented out:

```
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CourseID == id);
```

So, I get the same error on the line with just:

```
        var courseToUpdate = await _context.Courses;
```

All this code is in the courses controller and in the controller I have the namespaces:

1. using ContosoUniversity.Data; - to bring in the DbContext
2. using ContosoUniversity.Models; - to bring in the Course POCO

Here is the full POST Edit action:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var courseToUpdate = await _context.Courses;
                //.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CourseID == id);

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Course>(courseToUpdate,
                "",
                c => c.Credits, c => c.DepartmentID, c => c.DepartmentID, c => c.Title))
        {
            try
            {
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                // Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the probelem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

And here is the whole DbContext:

```
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OfficeAssignment> OfficeAssignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseAssignment> CourseAssignments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("Department");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().ToTable("Instructor");
            modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>().ToTable("OfficeAssignment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseAssignment>().ToTable("CourseAssignment");

            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseAssignment>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.CourseID, c.InstructorID });

        }
    }
}
```

I've just never seen this error before and I have no idea what it is trying to tell me.

I tried searching the error but it is always about Task of int or Task of string, never about a DbSet.
Anyone else ever run into this for returning a simple DbSet collection?

---

**UPDATE:**

I copied and pasted the POST Edit code right from the tutorial, cleaned, and rebuilt.
Now the squiggly just comes at the end of the block.
But it compiled successfully.
I'll just finish working through the page and see if it resolves.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to fetch all courses, you're probably looking for:

```
var courseToUpdate = await _context.Courses.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Oh my mistake. I added ToListAsync() on and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I reread your question and it's not fully clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to fetch the list of all courses? Or are you trying to fetch a single course and then update that? From the question it looks like the latter. And if that's true then @gurustron 's answer might be correct. You do have a redundant semicolon in there.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is copied as is - remove extra `;`:

```cs
var courseToUpdate = await _context.Courses
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CourseID == id);
```

`DbSet` itself is not awaitable by itself but contains a lot of operations which return `Task` which can be awaited (`FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `ToListAsync`, etc. see [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions?view=efcore-7.0) class).

Answer (score 0):

It finally started working everybody.

Usually when I get red squgglies in my code in Visual Studio I just keep typing because it may be the IDE is slow to catch up and remove the squigglys.
In this case it wasn't going away.
And when I would compile I would get the same error's as shown when I would hover over the red squiggly in code.
I just cleaned, rebuilt and finished typing in the code from the tutorial I was going through.  The compile errors went away in the output and errors window.  But still had strange squigglies in the code.
But the code ran fine.
I would just delete this post but when I hit the delete button Stack warns that if you delete too many questions they can lock your account.